# When relocating a home folder to another Volume, how do you resolve Sandbox errors for the new root .TemporaryItems folder?

Tags: security, data-synchronization, permission, ventura, sandbox

*Summary*:

I migrated my user data to a new APFS volume to mitigate upgrade issues with Ventura, but I am now experiencing high CPU usage with `syncdefaultsd` and `secd` due to permission issues. I need help to adjust Sandbox settings without breaking the security or stability of the system.

---

*Details*:

After some very lengthy "wars" with a multi-failed attempt to "upgrade" to Ventura, I was finally able to get some relief/success by first migrating my user data to a new APFS volume that lives beside the "system" volume. Apparently Apple engineers seem to believe this is the best course of action presently so as to mitigate "headaches" from failed upgrades and other issues...

When doing this I discovered that this works rather well, but I noticed that `syncdefaultsd` was running quite high on the CPUs. Looking into the logs more closely I found that both it and `secd` are having a problem with permission to the new user storage location, eg my new home folder is at `/Volumes/data/Users/username` and the error in question is:

```
...
1   <Missing Description>       kernel  Sandbox: secd(16636) deny(1) file-write-create /Volumes/data/.TemporaryItems/folders.501/TemporaryItems/path    0   0: 0x95619f error   17:57:51.167515-0400
...
1   <Missing Description>       kernel  Sandbox: syncdefaultsd(670) deny(1) file-write-create /Volumes/data/.TemporaryItems/folders.501/TemporaryItems/path 0   0: 0x956f00 error   17:58:00.614794-0400
...
```

What is the appropriate or acceptable method to deal with this without breaking Apple's methodology here?

Clearly (Seatbelt) `Sandbox` isn't configured to facilitate this and/or some system setting in Ventura is not liking the *automatic* move that macOS did to put `.TemporaryItems` into the new volume's root path.

I don't like the idea of removing all permissions on the drive and if I manually set them, a system service automatically re'chowns the folder to `root:wheel`, so I'm not seeing any clean or clear paths past this.

Another option, that would not be considered kosher, is to mount the System volume +rw and modify `com.apple.secd.sb` and `com.apple.syncdefaultsd.sb` in `/System/Library/Sandbox/Profiles/` so as to add:

```
(allow file-write-create
    (subpath "/Volumes/data/.TemporaryItems"))
```

Such that `com.apple.secd.sb` would be:

```
(version 1)

(deny default)

(import "system.sb")

(allow file-write-data
    (literal "/dev/random"))

(allow file-write-create
    (subpath "/Volumes/data/.TemporaryItems"))

(allow file-read* file-write*
    (subpath "/private/var/db/mds")
...
```

And `com.apple.syncdefaultsd.sb` would have this inserted:

```
...
(allow user-preference-read
    (preference-domain "com.apple.CloudKit")
    (preference-domain "kCFPreferencesAnyApplication"))

;; Read/write access to a temporary directory
(allow file-read* file-write*
    (subpath (param "TMPDIR"))
    (subpath (param "DARWIN_CACHE_DIR"))
    (subpath "/Volumes/data/.TemporaryItems"))
       
;; Read ourselves
(allow file-read*
    (subpath (param "SELF_PATH")))
...
```

But this is clearly both fragile and "insecure"... Thus my question: how *should* such a situation be handled when moving the home folder to a different volume and needing to accommodate Apple's Sandboxing?

---

As requested, here's the process I followed to "move" my user folder to the new APFS volume:

- Installed new system
- Upon user creation created user with same username as before
- Make new "admin" user and login as such
- Created new APFS volume
- `sudo rsync -avEX --progress /Users /Volume/data/`
- `cd /Volume/data/Users`
- `sudo rsync -avEX /Volume/data/Users/newly_created_username/ /Volume/data/Users/username.new_empty_username_backup`
- `sudo rsync -avEX --progress --remove-source-files /Volume/old_system/Users/username/  /Volumes/data/Users/newly_created_but_same_as_original_username/`
- Sanity check ownership, just in case so that UIDs match: `sudo chown -R username:staff /Volumes/data/Users/newly_created_but_same_as_original_username/`
- Log out and back in as username - deal with TCC, etc. and start using system.

Comment: How did you move/copy the user folder? In the past I have done just a "drag the folder in Finder" from another administrative account and then resetting the user folder path in the Users & Groups System Settings section. (control-click to get to the "advanced" settings). Though it has been a while. Some detail on how you moved/copied the user folder might be helpful...

Comment: Added for you at end of above post @SteveChambers.

Comment: I'd be tempted to try an experiment: copy your user folder to another location with the Finder and then set *that* as your default user folder. All of what you did looks like it should be OK (IMHO) but Apple designs macOS (and iOS, and iPadOS...) to be used by *non technical* users. Which does not include people comfortable with (or knowledgable about) Terminal.app. I would always start with the simplest way to do something before resorting to your shell of choice.